# Is dll static var shared between threads that load the same dll?

Tags: c++, multithreading, dll, static, sharing

here my issue. I have a mainApplication (c++ application) which launches K threads (c++ threads) at the application starts. Each thread has its own configuration. All k threads load the same Dll (myDll.dll) which has a static var X. Inside each thread, i have a function that prints the X address, and all threads print the same address value for X. So my question is: Is static var X, declared into Dll, shared between all threads?
I use windows and c++.
Kind regards.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Read this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dlls/dynamic-link-library-data#variable-scope

Basically, threads are not isolated from each other in any way, shape or form -- all threads in a program operate on the same memory. This notion extends to DLLs as well.

Comment: so, static dll var is stored into process' data segment, and shared between all threads inside process. Is it correct?

Comment: @MrMartins - You have `thread_local` for non-shared objects, the rest reside in a common address space.